# Is it safe to remove my Stack Exchange login?

Tags: support, openid

I've recently got a new email address, and I have added the login which uses my new address, however it counts as `other`. I can only change the password of my Stack Exchange login which isn't very helpful.

[image]

I have tried following these instructions: *[How can I change my Stack Exchange login email?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247605/how-can-i-change-my-stack-exchange-login-email)*. However, they appear to be out of date (`5. click add more logins... and select More login options` there isn't a `more options` button/link anymore...).

I seem to recall there were some changes happening r.e. OpenID, possibly to do with ditching it?

Can I safely remove the login without damaging my account across all sites?

---

### EDIT

Followed @animusin's instructions, but then remembered that was how the new email address was added to the `other` section in the first place, appears you can't add the same email twice, which seems sensible.
[image: When adding my new email (again)]

---

### EDIT 2

I have now removed my `other` login, and can't re-add it at all... mistakes were made ;_;

Comment: [Support for OpenID ends on July 1, 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ends-on-july-1-2018)

Answer (score 5):

If you've recently changed your email address and it's showing up under the Other section, then what you did was change your preferred contact address in your email settings, and it is now on your account as a verified email. This action alone does *not* allow you to login with that email, and removing your existing Stack Exchange login would lock you out of the account (which doesn't make it unrecoverable, just more difficult to get to the state you want).

All you need to do from that screenshot is click the add more logins button and then enter the same email address, along with a password, into the boxes that appear on the resulting page. It will probably ask you to confirm the email again before the credential is officially created. After that, the email will move up to the Stack Exchange section, which means you can login with that email address and whatever password you set for it.

You can then remove the other credential as you please.

Comment: I can't add a new login using that email address, I'm pretty sure I actually added the email address as a new login already (but can't log in with it...)

Comment: Any further advice? the above has not worked =[

Comment: @Troy What exact steps did you follow here? I see you have an OpenID account at the new email that was created ~5 minutes after you verified your email on-site, but I don't see it being connected to anything at all. I'd suggest opening an incognito window, logging in with the email and password combination you setup. Confirm to create a new profile, then contact us with links to both profiles and we can merge them together for you.

Comment: I tried creating a new OpenID account shortly after posting this question,  why is creating and merging accounts the only way to change an email address? Or did I go dun mess up?

Comment: Support contacted

Comment: Resolved, it **was** safe to remove once the old and new email addresses appeared in the `Stack Exchange` section

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately,

1. I removed the new email from the `other` section
2. I created a new OpenId account using my new email *([Note Support for OpenID ends on July 1, 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ends-on-july-1-2018) so this step will likely differ for you)*
3. [I followed these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge my old and new accounts
4. I then had two logins listed in the `Stack Overflow`section, each with a `change password` option, I removed the one with the old email and logged out then in again, and can still post this... Qapla'!